# Mask Indices in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like:

```
data=np.array([1,2,3,5,8,7,2,1,3,5,1,2,20])
```

I would like to mask an array indices with a step of 3.
For an example I able to mask where the value of an array equal to 3.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
x = np.array([1,2,3,5,8,7,2,1,3,5,1,2,20])
mx=ma.masked_values(x,3)
output:
[1 2 -- 5 8 7 2 1 -- 5 1 2 20]
```

Requirement:
I need to mask the every 3nd Indices in an array.(step of 3)

Required Output:

```
[1,2,3,--,8,7,--,1,3,--,1,2,--]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
mask = list(map(lambda i: i%3==2, np.arange(len(x))))
ma.masked_array(x, mask=mask)
```

Output:

```
masked_array(data=[1, 2, --, 5, 8, --, 2, 1, --, 5, 1, --, 20],
             mask=[False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,
                    True, False, False,  True, False],
       fill_value=999999)
```

Comment: Thanaks a lot for your help.

Comment: Dear sir. How can I implement the above code for two dimensional arary.

Comment: can you provide your input and desired output?

Comment: example: 
I have an array like
x=np.array([[1,2,3,5,8,7,2,1,3,5,1,2,20,21],[3,8,3,9,8,7,10,1,3,5,1,2,20,21]])

Required output: 
[[1 2 3 -- 8 7 -- 1 3 -- 1 2 -- 21],[3 8 3 -- 8 7 -- 1 3 -- 1 2 -- 21]]

Comment: use this `import numpy.ma as ma` 
`mask = list(map(lambda i: i%3==2, np.arange(len(x.T))))`
 `ma.masked_array(x, mask=[mask]*2)`

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. Its functions

Answer (score 3):

Let us create a mask based on the indices of the array:

```
np.ma.masked_array(x, np.r_[1, 1:len(x)] % 3 == 0)
```

---

```
masked_array(data=[1, 2, 3, --, 8, 7, --, 1, 3, --, 1, 2, --],
             mask=[False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False,
                   False,  True, False, False,  True],
       fill_value=999999)
```